# Is setNeedsUpdateContraints() ignoring me?

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I have a Storyboard that uses Auto Layout & Size Classes. I've given up trying to get my UIView to use the Aspect Ratio 1:1 constraint to work. It takes over the entire screen rather than just set height = width like a UIImageViewer does.

So I am trying to change the width and height constraints instead. In IB the width constraint is set to 320 and the height constraint is set to 320. Ultimately I will set the width constraint to the width of the device and the height constraint to the width of the device, hopefully getting a square UIView for the camera to display its session.

However, when I set the constants and then setNeedsUpdateContraints, nothing happens. Yes I would prefer not to do it this way, but I would also prefer to get this &^*&$^*#( thing to work and not spend any more hours fighting it. Setting leading space to 0, trailing space to 0, top space to 0, and aspect ratio 1:1 does not work. Even though I did it with a UIImageView and it does work for that.

```
@IBOutlet var captureFrame: UIView!
@IBOutlet var viewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet var viewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.viewWidthConstraint.constant = 100  //100 = temporary
    self.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 100  //100 = temporary
    captureFrame.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    captureFrame.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Any idea how to get a square UIView so that the camera can be displayed in it using IB, auto layout, size classes AND not have it zoomed in X2?

Why aren't my constraints adjusting to 100? Why is my UIView still 320 x 320?

Comment: I don't know why your aspect ratio constraint isn't working. When I do like you said (0 constraints to top, left, and right, and a 1:1 aspect ratio constraint) it works fine for me (it will look like it takes the whole screen in IB because the view is 600x600, but it will be correct at runtime).

Comment: Exactly. I would expect it to but it doesn't. I've spent 8 hours trying to get it to work . And get this, it looks perfect in the preview in IB in all devices. BUT, when I run it on the device, the UIView is HUGE. Covers the entire screen and you can tell it is going off the screen.

But a UIImageView behaves as expected on the device. 

It must be something with: var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

I even tried to set the bottom constraint to a button. That makes it look right but the camera looks zoomed in by x2. If I make the size 320x320 on all devices it works perfectly

Comment: Are there any constraint conflict errors being logged?

Comment: No. No errors at all.

Comment: I couldn't waste anymore time on it. I would prefer to use the aspect ratio constraint. The width & height constraints were just a work around. So workaround two is to just create the view in code and add it as a subview instead of using IB. This works so until someone can help get my aspect ratio fixed, this is the route I've gone so I can continue working.